# UnicodeEncodeError when trying to visualize data using offline.plot method

Tags: python, plotly, histogram, graph-visualization

The program imports die from a Die class which represents a single 6 sided die. Simulates the die roll for 1000 times and counts frequency of every outcome. When trying to visualize data using offline.plotly I get error:

UnicodeEncodeError: 'charmap' codec can't encode character '\u25c4' in position 276398: character maps to

In the error there is also underlined problem: return f.write(data)
I have looked into information that is stored in data variable but it looks correct to put it in offline.plot() method.

Also there is no encoding parameter to be passed in this method.
Here is code:

```
from plotly.graph_objs import Bar, Layout
from plotly import offline
from die import Die

# Create D6
die = Die()

results = []

for roll_num in range(1000):
    result = die.roll()
    results.append(result)

# Analyze the results.
frequencies = []

for value in range(1, die.num_sides + 1):
    frequency = results.count(value)
    frequencies.append(frequency)

# Visualize the results.
x_values = list(range(1, die.num_sides + 1))
data = [Bar(x=x_values, y=frequencies)]
x_axis_config = {'title': 'Result'}
y_axis_config = {'title': 'Frequency of Result'}
my_layout = Layout(title='Results of rolling one D6 1000 times', xaxis=x_axis_config, yaxis=y_axis_config)
offline.plot({'data': data, 'layout': my_layout}, filename='d6.html')
```

Answer (score 0):

Let's downgrade version to 5.11.0 (from Oct, 27 2022) - I've got the same issue going through exercises.

Check the Release history on PyPi.org
https://pypi.org/project/plotly/#history

Works for me after downgrade.

Answer (score 0):

From looking at plotly's Github issues, upgrading to version 5.13.0 should solve your problem. https://github.com/plotly/plotly.py/issues/3898

Ran into this today using 5.12.0 while saving HTML plots and upgrading to 5.13.0 resolved the error for me.

Answer (score 0):

yes i did pip list in the command line and saw my plotly version was 5.12, when I installed to 5.13 it worked.
unsure if there was an issue with which folder sublime text uses for plotly since i may have installed it on both command line and within sublime text

Comment: This would be more beneficial as a comment. Sharing experiences etc. are helpful but answers should be kept for detailed responses providing a direct answer.